# input text in IE using excel vba error

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

Ive been trying to input text in IE using VBA but i keep getting object doesnt support this property
the url I'm trying to input test is 
http://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/s/2XKL1/

my code is

```
Sub inputusername()
Dim IE As Object
Dim name As String


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

currenttime = Hour(Now())

If currenttime < 12 Then
    g01 = "Morning"
ElseIf currenttime >= 18 Then
    g01 = "Evening"
Else
    g01 = "Afternoon"
End If
'Me.embtn.Visible = True
'MsgBox (g01 & " " & Application.UserName)
If MsgBox(g01 & " " & Application.UserName & " Please input your name on the website?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then
    name = InputBox("Please type in your name")
Else
    name = Application.UserName
End If
'MsgBox (Name)
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("http://www.smartsurvey.co.uk/s/2XKL1/")
    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    IE.doucment.getelementsByName("t31092740").innertext = name
    IE.document.getelementsByName("cmdGo").Item.Click
End With
' cleaning up memory
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

MsgBox "Yippy Thanks"

End Sub
```

I have tried replacing `IE.doucment.getelementsByName("t31092740").innertext`
with `IE.doucment.getelementsByName("t31092740").innerhtml` ;
`IE.doucment.getelementsByID("t31092740").innertext`  but keep geting object does not support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Need to use Item (or first item by using ...("t31092749")(0).Value)

2- Need to use Value property

Try:

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("t31092740").Item.Value = name
```

Note: It is "document" of course. I assume it is typo in your code.